# Element keeps changing when removing and adding width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a `nav-item` which keeps changing when adding or removing a `width: 100%;`. I'm using Bootstrap 4, and this really is the first time I've ever seen something like this.

See the gif I made: [image]

You can check it out for yourself here: [cwdekker.nl](http://cwdekker.nl)

Comment: What's your actual question, Chris? And what exactly do you expect when messing with css like that? I mean, wouldn't you expect that things break when you take them away?

Comment: @WebDevBooster My question is if anyone knows why this may be happening. I mean I would expect it to change if you take things away but not like this. It keeps moving the element further left somehow

Comment: Chris, in order for me to help you fix the issue I first need to understand what the actual issue is. And right now, I'm clueless. Can you fill me in?

Comment: @WebDevBooster Well, if you look at the navbar in the image, you can see that the `nav-item` is moving everytime I remove/add the width until it somehow reaches a full width and the text is next to each other.

Comment: Fair enough, Chris. But you don't expect your website visitors to do what you are doing in that gif. Do you?

Comment: @WebDevBooster True, but it still isn't supposed to happen. It looks like something is bugging on the website but I can't see what it is..

Comment: Chris this of course will happen if you changed the width the items need to fit inslide the navbar but you changed the width(which is strange) so they re positioned, you are doing that?

Comment: @mohammedqudah But wouldn't they change back to their old position if I re-add the width? I mean, it now just moves the elements to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using custom css hacks for simple things like spacing you should be using the native spacing classes provided by Bootstrap 4. That alone should immediately fix your issue.

The padding and margin classes in Bootstrap 4 are `p-*` and `m-*` respectively.

To add horizontal padding on both sides, you can use `px-*` whereas the `*` should be replaced with a number between 0 and 5.

To add padding to the right, you use the `pr-*` class (padding-right); `pb-*` for padding-bottom etc.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Glad to hear that!